# Scalability of Clustered Listeners in Infinispan for Cache with many Keys?

Tags: scalability, infinispan

When using an embedded cache in Infinispan I'm looking to have a filtered Clustered listener that is notified every time a specific key is updated. My problem is that the time it takes for the cache to check which listeners should be notified when a value is updated is an O(n) operation, with no performance gains with more nodes in my cluster. This means that I can't scale my cluster to handle large amount of keys.

This is likely because the following code snippet in `CacheNotifierImpl` that goes through all of the listeners:

```java
   private CompletionStage<Void> doNotifyModified(K key, V value, Metadata metadata, V previousValue,
         Metadata previousMetadata, boolean pre, InvocationContext ctx, FlagAffectedCommand command) {
      if (clusteringDependentLogic.running().commitType(command, ctx, extractSegment(command, key), false).isLocal()
            && (command == null || !command.hasAnyFlag(FlagBitSets.PUT_FOR_STATE_TRANSFER))) {
         EventImpl<K, V> e = EventImpl.createEvent(cache.wired(), CACHE_ENTRY_MODIFIED);
         boolean isLocalNodePrimaryOwner = isLocalNodePrimaryOwner(key);
         Object batchIdentifier = ctx.isInTxScope() ? null : Thread.currentThread();
         try {
            AggregateCompletionStage<Void> aggregateCompletionStage = null;
            for (CacheEntryListenerInvocation<K, V> listener : cacheEntryModifiedListeners) {
               // Need a wrapper per invocation since converter could modify the entry in it
               configureEvent(listener, e, key, value, metadata, pre, ctx, command, previousValue, previousMetadata);
               aggregateCompletionStage = composeStageIfNeeded(aggregateCompletionStage,
                     listener.invoke(new EventWrapper<>(key, e), isLocalNodePrimaryOwner));
```

where the `listener.invoke` function checks the filter of each listener to see if the function should be invoked or not. This means that every node will always have to iterate through every listener for every event, just to find that almost all listeners are no-ops.

Is there any smooth non O(n) way to add a cluster wide listener where the core library identifies that the listener should only be triggered for a specific key?

This behavior has been found when using version `13.0.0` of the `infinispan-core` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a filter or even a converter that is applied on the primary node before sending to the node where the cluster listener is registered. If the filter denies that event it will not send it remotely and will not notify the listener.

The supplied converter can be used to change the value sent to the listener, which could be something like returning a single variable from the key or value instead of the entire thing, possibly reducing the payload size.

https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#event_filtering_and_conversion

Note this means that your supplied filter and converter must be marshallable by Infinispan as we ship those between nodes.

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I have a clustered listener on modify in a cache, it's filter will be tried for **every** modify event in that that happens on **every** node. This means that if I have a cluster with a cache with 1_000_000 keys and listeners, every modify in this cache will have to check 1_000_000 filters to see if they are relevant to the change. This is why the execution time of updates grow linearly with the amount of listeners and this is what I need to circumvent.

Comment: It is not on *every* node with a cluster listener. The filter is only applied on the primary owner of said key. If it is then you have ran into a bug.

Every filter is evaluated for each event on the primary owner; the point is to avoid the remote transfer of the event, not the evaluation of said filters. The remote transfer of the event is orders of magnitude more expensive than a filter evaluation which should be all in memory.

Comment: When you say "The filter is only applied on the primary owner of said key" do you mean that the filter will only return true for events on this node, or do you mean that the filter is only **evaluated** on the primary owner? 

If the filter is evaluated on all non primary owner nodes for the key as well (where it can never be true) I have the O(n) case as mentioned in my question and my problem is unfortunately not solved.